# Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, package-name

when i run react-native run-android i get this error, i was installing react-native firebase I did all configuration to get this to work and just at the end it seems to be a package name error.

The thing is that I already checked the files : 
- /android/build.gradle
- /android/app/build.gradle
- /android/app/src/main/com/AndroidManifest.xml 
- /android/app/src/main/com/myapp/MainActivity.java 
- /android/app/src/main/com/myapp/MainApplication.java
- /android/app/google-services.json

they have the exact same packageName

I Also tried to add change in AndroidManifest.xml the lines ".MainApplication" and ".MainActivity" to "com.myapp.MainApplication" and "com.myapp.MainActivity"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it was a duplicate state of  in AndroidManifest.xml that caused that error, check yours

Comment: what does it mean duplicate state?